# how to force build when ever a page shows up in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello hope you guys are ok.
the problem I'm facing is we have a main_page which leads to a page doing some changes on data which are show on the main page.
after some process if the user touches back button and goes to main_page app loads it from stack and the data are not shown because it does not get rebuilt.
I don't want to control back button because there are other pages which lead to data changing page and I also tried using valuelistenablebuilder but I don't know why it goes wild and gets into a screen refresh loop without even changing the valueListenable I used redux to manage the value.
actual reason I want main page to rebuild is to call a method. why do I not call that method in second page is complicated and because i don't want to.

in conclusion I want main page to rebuild whenever it **shows up** even when it's read from the **stack** or even is there a way to tamper with stack of the pages without visual changes to the user.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Shared preferences plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: my question is not about state management its about stack changes and the lower stack does not get rebuilt forcefully when the upper stack pops.
i know i can use a call back function but its not efficient for my situation im also using redux but its not rebuilding on value change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly

The flow should be:

Screen A

```
@override
void initState() {
 loadSomeDataFromDB();
 super.initState();
}
```

Screen B

```
@override
void initState() { *//INIT AS EXAMPLE*
 changeSomeDataFromDB();
 super.initState();
}
```

You can try this in Screen A

```
 onPressed: () async {
            bool? shouldLoadDataAgain = await 
            Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
              pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
                  const ScreenB(),
            ));
            if(shouldLoadDataAgain!=null&&shouldLoadDataAgain ==true){
             loadSomeDataFromDB();
            }
          },
```

and this in Screen B when user press back button

```
  onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(true)
          },
```

Comment: well you have understood the flow right but i don't want to control back button because there are man routes to the page B and the data could have been changed on page B so page A needs to update. I don't know why storeconnector of redux does not rebuild the page A on change.

Answer (score 0):

solution for my problem was that used redux store had an object and updating object property or a list does not count as variable change to redux so the widget wouldn't rebuild.